# Python set operations - complement union of set

Tags: python, discrete-mathematics

I am in a Discrete Math course and am trying to replicate De Morgan's law of

> Complement(B union C) = Complement(B) intersect Complement(C).

I tried searching for Python's ability to perform a complement on a set, but I didn't see much if anything.

So I just tried this in IDLE. Does this appear correct?

```
U = {'pink', 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'gray', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'indigo', 'violet'}
A = {'purple', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'violet'}
B = {'blue', 'gray', 'orange', 'green'}
C = {'pink', 'red','blue','violet'}
Comp_B = U - B
Comp_C = U - C
Comp_Union_BC = Comp_B.intersection(Comp_C)
print(Comp_Union_BC)
```

Comment: The complement of a set is *everything else*. What is *everything else* here?

Comment: "Without a definition of the universal set, you can't really give a definition of the complement of a set". That answered my question. It would be neat if Python had a function built in that took a defined set as a parameter then you could work with it. Perhaps I need to make this for the Python standard library. 

Comment: but as shown, `complement(a)` is really just an alias for `U.difference(a)`. You could just use `complement = U.difference`.

Answer (score 12):

The complement of a set is everything *not* in the set, but part of the 'universal set'. Without a definition of the universal set, you can't really give a standard-library definition of *the complement of a set*.

Moreover, the Python `set` type deals in sets of discrete objects, not a mathematical construct that could be infinitely large, such as *all natural numbers*. So Python doesn't support the general, nebulous and infinite idea of a single universal set.

For specific domains, if you can define the universal set in discrete terms, simply define your own `complement()` callable. For example, given a global definition of the universal set *U*, you can define the complement of a set `a` as the difference between *U* and that set:

```
U = {'pink', 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'gray', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'indigo', 'violet'}

def complement(a):
    # difference between a global universal set U and the given set a
    return U - a
```

or, simpler still:

```
complement = U.difference
```

Then just pass a set to `complement()` to test the hypothesis:

```
>>> # set | set == set union, set & set == set intersection
...
>>> complement(B | C) == complement(B) & complement(C)
True
```

So yes, your interpretation is correct, `U - B` produces the complement of `B`.

Comment: He did define the Universal Set... it's `U = {'pink', 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'gray', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'indigo', 'violet'}`

Comment: @HarisNadeem: yes, my answer was trying to address why Python does not define the `complement` operation for sets.

Comment: my mistake, I misread your answer. You are correct. +1 upvote

Answer (score 0):

What if you extend the `set` class, I mean creating a subclass of `set`. This class will have a property called complement that will facilitate to corroborate De Morgan's law. Make sure to override the `union` method.

```
class Set(set):
    def __init__(self, s=(), U=None):
        super().__init__(s)
        self.U = U

    def union(self, A):
        return Set(super().union(A), self.U)

    @property
    def complement(self):
        if U is None:
            raise Exception('Universal set not defined')
        return Set(self.U - self, self.U)

U = {'pink', 'purple', 'red', 'blue', 'gray', 'orange', 'green', 'yellow', 'indigo', 'violet'}
A = Set({'purple', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'violet'}, U)
B = Set({'blue', 'gray', 'orange', 'green'}, U)
C = Set({'pink', 'red','blue','violet'}, U)
```

Now, you just have to run the following:

```
>>> B.union(C).complement == B.complement.intersection(C.complement)
True
```